# PHP MySQL: User selects the fields to create mysql query array variable

Tags: php, mysql

here's my problem:

I have a form in which user inputs 3 things (ID key, Date from and Date To) and also from a group o checkboxes he chooses which columns he wants to see in the result. (the form is way to big because its database table has about 15 columns each, so I don't post it here)

here is the (part of the) code which handles these inputs and generates the query. (I'll explain after it what exactly does)

```
<?php
//Check the columns that should be shown in the table
if(empty($_POST['vesselcolumns']) && empty($_POST['expeditioncolumns'])){
    $columns='*';
}else if (isset($_POST['vesselcolumns']) || isset($_POST['expeditioncolumns'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['vesselcolumns'])){
        $columns='';
    }else{
        $vesselcolumns= implode(',', $_POST['vesselcolumns']);
        $columns=$vesselcolumns;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['expeditioncolumns'])){
        $columns.='';
    }else{
        $expeditioncolumns = implode(',', $_POST['expeditioncolumns']);
        if($columns!=''){
            $columns.=','.$expeditioncolumns;
        }
    }
}

//AMAS check
if(empty($_POST['searchv'])){
    echo 'No AMAS given, will print ALL expedition data<br />';
}else{
    $amas = $_POST['searchv'];
}

//Deploy Date FROM and TO check
if(empty($_POST['deploydatefrom'])){
    $datefrom = '0000-00-00';
}else{
    $datefrom = $_POST['deploydatefrom'];
}

if(empty($_POST['deploydateto'])){
    $dateto = '9999-12-31';
}else{
    $dateto = $_POST['deploydateto'];
}

if(isset($amas)){
    $expeditionq="SELECT '$columns' 
        FROM vessel
        INNER JOIN vessel_expeditions
        ON vessel.AMAS=vessel_expeditions.vexpedition_AMAS AND vessel.AMAS= '$amas'
        INNER JOIN expedition
        ON vessel_expeditions.expedition_ID=expedition.expedition_ID
        WHERE expedition.deployDate >= '$datefrom' AND expedition.deployDate <= '$dateto'";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$expeditionq);

    if($columns=='*'){
        $takefields=mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM vessel"); 

        while ($vcol = mysqli_fetch_array($takefields)){
            $vcolu= array( $vcol['Field']);
        }

        $takefieldse=mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM expedition");

        while ($ecol = mysqli_fetch_array($takefieldse)){
            $ecolu= array($ecol['Field']);
        }

        $vccounter = count($vcolu);
        $eccounter = count($ecolu);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            for($i=0; $i<$vccounter; $i++){
                echo $row[$vcolu[$i]] . '<br />';
            }

            for($i=0; $i<$eccounter; $i++){
                echo $row[$ecolu[$i]] . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }else{
        $column = explode(',', $columns);
        $counter = count($column);
        $forexport='<table id="results">
                        <tr>';
        for($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++){
            $forexport .= '<th>' . $column[$i] . '</th>';
        }

        $forexport.='</tr>';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            for($i=0; $i<=$counter; $i++){
                $forexport .= '<td>' . $row[$column[$i]] . '</td>';
            }
            $forexport.='</tr>';
        }

        $forexport .='</table>';

        echo $forexport;
        echo '<form name="exportanalysis" method="post" action="exportanalysis.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="export" value="' . htmlspecialchars($forexport, ENT_QUOTES) . '" />
                <label for="selectcsv"><img src="img/csv-icon.png" width="50" height="50" /> </label>
                <input type="radio" name="filexport" value="csv" id="selectcsv" required />
                <label for="selectxls"><img src="img/xls-icon.png" width="50" height="50" /> </label>
                <input type="radio" name="filexport" value="xls" id="selectxls" />
                <input type="submit" value="Download" />';
    }
}else{
    echo 'amas not set';
}
?>
```

First I check which columns has user selected (if none selected I put `"*"`) and I break them in an array with implode (as from the checkboxes they come in string like this: `column1`,`column2`,`column4`, `etc.`).

Then I check the AMAS (which is the ID key user inputs) and finally I check the dates if given [strange thing here when I submitted the form without date values with isset() even though there was no value in them it kept passing the if(as they were set) so I changed it to empty()].

After multiple tests I've found out that the query (`$expeditionq`) works fine (I even tested it in MySQL directly). Also the `"SHOW COLUMNS"` queries work fine and I fetch their results and showed them.

The problem comes when I'm trying to show the results of the `$expeditionq` query and I assume that the problem is this: `$row[$column[$i]]` but I cannot figure out another way to do it :/

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: I cannot show the results from mysqli_fetch_array($result)

Answer (score 1):

Puh. Sorry this code looks weired. Is this what you want to express:

```
  if(!empty($_POST['vesselcolumns']) && !empty($_POST['expeditioncolumns'])){
    $columns= implode(',', $_POST['vesselcolumns']) . ',' . implode(',', $_POST['expeditioncolumns']);
  }
  else if(!empty($_POST['vesselcolumns'])) {
     $columns= implode(',', $_POST['vesselcolumns']);
  }
  else if(!empty($_POST['expeditioncolumns'])) {
     $columns= implode(',', $_POST['expeditioncolumns']) 
  }
  else {
      $columns='*';
  }
```

Anyway, the problem is just obvious:
**SHOW COLUMNS will return all columns in that table. 
You iterating over the result, which contains only the columns the user selected.
So you are trying to access alphanumeric indexes or "keys" within the row that dont exist unless the user has requested to show all columns.** 
 EDIT: Sorry, this was an incomplete reading due to the unstructured way the source is organized. The query SHOW COLUMNS is only executed, when $columns == "*", so all fields are selected obviously.

Comment: the code you posted is the same (I wrote it more "amateurish" way). The SHOW COLUMNS query is only used when I want to show all the columns I get (as $columns = "*") so the should be no problem with it. Please explain if I didn't get it right.

Comment: Yes I corrected my answer right before your comment. Still, if you can downtrace your problem to that you think it is the $row access, start using functions such as var_dump($row) and echo $column[$i] to see if the key is there.

Comment: Besides: I don't want to correct you nor the way you are coding. It's just a matter of production experience: It's always good to write your code as clean and readable as possible, both for you and other people. Imagine not touching a project for months whilst been working on another one. You will find much faster into it.

Comment: I have already done a couple of things, $column[$i] works fine and prints out the name of each column. So for $row what do you suggest... In fact I was wondering if is it possible to do this, it's like $array[$array[$var]] ...

Comment: Yes, of course. The inner expression is evaluated first and the underlying operator for [const char *] in the array - struct in the zend - egine is called, returning the value for that key. This value is then used for the second call to the operator[const char *] which will give you the value of the element with that key in that array. So it's like $array['A'] = 'B', $key = 'A', $array[$key] == $array['A'] == 'B' and subsequently it's $array2[$array[$key]] == $array2[$array['A']] == $array2['B']. (the zendengine implementation is a little bit different then described, I just wanted

Comment: to use this as an example.) Actually operator - calls such as the [0] or ['A'] are pretty much like function calls internally, the return a value just like a function.

Comment: So is the error in the part which contains all fields ("*") or only with the user - selected fields?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is applied on both conditions. Anyway, I'm pretty exhausted with it for today, so I'll take a fresh look of it tomorrow so I'll post any solution to this problem. (Solution that I HOPE I'll find :D )

Comment: Haha, okay. One thing left: Check your results before using them. mysq_query and mysqli_query don't necessaryly return valid resultsets but false, e.g.